# IEx block with sudo and System.cmd("mount")

Tags: linux, elixir, elixir-mix, elixir-iex

Some precision :

```
$> iex --version
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

IEx 1.4.4

$> mix --version
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Mix 1.4.4
```

I'm a french people and i don't understand why

```
$> iex -S mix
```

have some bugs with :

```
$> sudo iex -S mix
```

I want execute the command in IEx :

```
System.cmd("mount", ["-t", "ecryptfs", ".private", "private", "-o", ~s(key=passphrase,passphrase_passwd="pass",ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_passthrough=n)], [stderr_to_stdout: true])
```

For test and mount a *ecryptfs* partition. In

```
$> iex -S mix
iex(2)> System.cmd("mount", ["-t", "ecryptfs", ".private", "private", "-o", ~s(key=passphrase,passphrase_passwd="pass",ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_passthrough=n)], [stderr_to_stdout: true])

{"mount: mount : seul le superutilisateur peut utiliser l'option « --options »\n",1}
```

And I have the correct value, unprivileged *mount*.

With:

```
$> sudo iex -S mix
iex(2)> System.cmd("mount", ["-t", "ecryptfs", ".private", "private", "-o", ~s(key=passphrase,passphrase_passwd="pass",ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_passthrough=n)], [stderr_to_stdout: true])
```

The command bugs and prints anything. It just block. Without return error code, without anything, just blocking. IEx don't print anything.

I have a screenshot for that bug :

[image]

Comment: What happens if you run the command directly in the shell? `sudo mount -t ecryptfs .private private -o 'key=passphrase,passphrase_passwd="pass",ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_passthrough=n'`? Does it finish executing instantly? Does it ask for a password or anything?

Comment: So, the sudo password is asking, but It print `Select cipher: 
 1) aes: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 2) blowfish: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 56
 3) des3_ede: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 24; max keysize = 24
 4) twofish: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 5) cast6: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 6) cast5: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 5; max keysize = 16
Selection [aes]: ` so, i have precise this in the command ?

Comment: Yes, if you can somehow specify that value in CLI arguments so that it doesn't prompt this from the user, it should work from `System.cmd`.

Comment: I think I, I will create a type for option for my module with all specified value. Thinks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, System.cmd don't want to quote in argument. Okay. :/